# Animating With Gloss in Haskell

Tags: animation, haskell, graphics

Here's my code for a little pattern that looks something like this. (Not the most efficient code I know). Now, I want to make `stars` rotate using `animate`. but I'm not sure how to use `display` and `animate` together in one program. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Gloss Image]

```
import Graphics.Gloss

main = display (InWindow "Gloss" (700,700) (0,0))
           black (picture 100)
picture :: Float -> Picture
picture 0 = text "Value cannot be 0"
picture number = scale 6.5 6.5 (color rose $ drawpicture number)

orangered, orangered2, orangered3 :: Color
orangered = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.7
orangered2 = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.5
orangered3 = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.3

intervalsmall = [0,11.25,22.5,33.75,45,56.25,67.5,78.75]
intervalbig = [0,22.5,45,67.5,90,112.5,135,157.5,180,202.5,225,247.5,270,292.5,315,337.5]
xlist = [2,4..50]
ylist = [0,2..48]

squares = pictures[rotate x (line [(-50,0),(0,50),(50,0),(0,-50),(-50,0)]) | x <- intervalsmall]
stars = pictures[rotate x ((pictures [line [(-8.5,0),(0,50),(8.5,0)],line[(0,50),(0,0)]])) | x <- intervalbig]
grid = pictures[line [(0,y),(x,50)] | x <- xlist, y <- ylist, x-y==2]
insidegrid = pictures[
    translate 0 (-50) grid,
    rotate 90 (translate 0 (-50) grid),
    rotate 180 (translate 0 (-50) grid),
    rotate 270 (translate 0 (-50) grid)]

drawpicture :: Float -> Picture
drawpicture number = pictures [
    color red (pictures [circle 50,circle 8.5]),
    line [(-50,-50),(-50,50),(50,50),(50,-50),(-50,-50)],
    squares,
    scale 0.7 0.7 squares,
    scale 0.49 0.49 squares,
    scale 0.347 0.347 squares,
    scale 0.242 0.242 squares,
    color orange stars,
    color orange (scale 0.178 0.178 stars),
    rotate 11.25 (scale 0.178 0.178 stars), 
    translate (-50) 0 grid,
    rotate 90 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    rotate 180 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    rotate 270 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    color orangered insidegrid,
    color orangered2 (rotate 45 insidegrid),
    color orangered3 (rotate 22.5 insidegrid),
    color orangered3 (rotate 67.5 insidegrid)
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier if you have separate draw functions for each visual element, but the basic answer is: to animate it just use the `animate` function and `rotate` the image components you desire to "move":

```
import Graphics.Gloss

main = animate (InWindow "Gloss" (700,700) (0,0))
           black picture

picture :: Float -> Picture
picture 0 = text "Value cannot be 0"
picture number = scale 6.5 6.5 (color rose $ drawpicture number)

orangered, orangered2, orangered3 :: Color
orangered = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.7
orangered2 = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.5
orangered3 = makeColor 1.0 0.251 0.0 0.3

intervalsmall = [0,11.25,22.5,33.75,45,56.25,67.5,78.75]
intervalbig = [0,22.5,45,67.5,90,112.5,135,157.5,180,202.5,225,247.5,270,292.5,315,337.5]
xlist = [2,4..50]
ylist = [0,2..48]

squares = pictures[rotate x (line [(-50,0),(0,50),(50,0),(0,-50),(-50,0)]) | x <- intervalsmall]
stars = pictures[rotate x ((pictures [line [(-8.5,0),(0,50),(8.5,0)],line[(0,50),(0,0)]])) | x <- intervalbig]
grid = pictures[line [(0,y),(x,50)] | x <- xlist, y <- ylist, x-y==2]
insidegrid = pictures[
    translate 0 (-50) grid,
    rotate 90 (translate 0 (-50) grid),
    rotate 180 (translate 0 (-50) grid),
    rotate 270 (translate 0 (-50) grid)]

rotVal :: Float -> Float
rotVal x = x - (x / (2*pi))

drawpicture :: Float -> Picture
drawpicture number = pictures [
    rot $ color red (pictures [circle 50,circle 8.5]),
    line [(-50,-50),(-50,50),(50,50),(50,-50),(-50,-50)],
    rot $ squares,
    rot $ scale 0.7 0.7 squares,
    rot $ scale 0.49 0.49 squares,
    rot $ scale 0.347 0.347 squares,
    rot $ scale 0.242 0.242 squares,
    rot $ color orange stars,
    rot (color orange (scale 0.178 0.178 stars)),
    rot (rotate 11.25 (scale 0.178 0.178 stars)),
    translate (-50) 0 grid,
    rotate 90 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    rotate 180 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    rotate 270 (Translate (-50) 0 grid),
    rot $ color orangered insidegrid,
    rot $ color orangered2 (rotate 45 insidegrid),
    rot $ color orangered3 (rotate 22.5 insidegrid),
    rot $ color orangered3 (rotate 67.5 insidegrid)
    ]
  where rot = rotate (rotVal number)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too much to write out all for you but you just have to add another argument to your picture function that is a `Float` and represents time.  So `display` would be replaced by `animate`.  So.

```
main = animate (InWindow "Gloss" (700,700) (0,0))
           black (picture 100)

picture :: Float -> Float -> Picture
picture number time = -- whatever you have to do
```

You'll have to change your helping drawing functions to take this time param.  Let's say you want to rotate the whole think once ever 5 seconds you can just multiply this time coming in and get an angle `angle = time*(pi*2/5)` then you can use this angle for trig functions to calculate new x and y positions from the center.